# Why is my brand new USB memory not visible?

Tags: sd-card, usb-device

I have bought a nano SD card, which includes a USB reader. When I plug it, I can see it with `dmesg`:

```
[721825.906705] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 42 using ehci-pci
[721826.019724] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=1212, bcdDevice= 1.00
[721826.019726] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[721826.019727] usb 2-1.6: Product: Mass Storage Device
[721826.019728] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Generic
[721826.019729] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 121220160204
[721826.020131] usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[721826.020277] scsi host5: usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
[721827.031260] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[721827.031545] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
```

And also with `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 041: ID 14cd:1212 Super Top microSD card reader (SY-T18)
```

But parted does not see it. It seems it is not attached to a file in `/dev`, at least not `/dev/sd*`. It is not visible with `parted` nor `fdisk` too.

I am under Debian Buster. Any idea please (other posts have not helped me: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64103/sd-card-not-accessible-works-in-an-old-nokia-though), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64811/why-is-my-sd-card-not-being-recognized), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625243/my-usb-flash-memory-is-not-detected-in-linux-but-is-detected-in-windows), [4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429303/why-does-my-usb-device-not-appear-on-dev))?

**EDIT:** *I have tested the same SD-card with another USB adaptor, this time the SD card is associated with file `/dev/sdg1` and I can see it in parted. It is not the same manufacturer. So I assume the one which does not work is too recent for my kernel.*

Comment: `lsblk` tell you anything interesting?

Comment: it's *very* unlikely this has anything to do with your kernel. Again, `lsblk` output, please?

Answer (score 1):

Late response, but I have had the same issue and it seems to be an issue if you have a USB3 port on your host and the attached device (mostly cheap usb card readers or disk adapters) doesn't follow the spec properly.

The workaround is to disable UAS for the specific device.

In short in my arch I just added this file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/super-top-disable-uas.conf
```

With the following content:

```
options usb-storage quirks=14cd:168a:u
```

And then rebooted, and then the device showed up.

EDIT: I noticed your device has id: 14cd:**1212**, so just replace my 14cd:**168a** with your id, hope it work for you too :)

For more details check:
https://leo.leung.xyz/wiki/How_to_disable_USB_Attached_Storage_(UAS)